# In Atlassian Markdown is it possible to highlight single line in code block

Tags: markdown, bitbucket-server

In writing markdown for Atlassian Bitbucket, I would like to show a code block with one line highlighted (**NOT "Syntax Highlighting" as for a programming language, but one line bold**).  Is this possible?  There is no suggestion that it is possible at https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASH038/Markdown+syntax+guide

Comment: No, I don't believe this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with Atlassian Markdown, nor with standard markdown.

You can use **a separate code block** with bold text in it.

**Usage:**

```
    lorem

**`ipsum`**

    dolor sit amet
```

**Result:**

```
lorem
```

**`ipsum`**

```
dolor sit amet
```

Alternatively, you can use a [bold text generator](https://lingojam.com/BoldTextGenerator), but since it does not use a monospaced font, it can hurt readability. Also, some old browsers/fonts are not cabable of displaying the characters in the modified text.

Example:

```
lorem

dolor sit amet
```